# Adding node to SQL Server XML is silently failing

Tags: sql-server, xml

Trying to figure out why this snippet does not work.

```
DECLARE @changeStatus XML, @changeSet XML

SELECT @changeSet = TOP 1 ChangeSet 
FROM MyTable

SET @changeStatus = '<change id="' + CAST(NEWID() AS NVARCHAR(36)) + '" by="' + @authorizingUserName + '" byAccountId="' + CAST(@authorizingUserId AS NVARCHAR(36)) + '" when="' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50),GETUTCDATE(),127) + 'Z">'
                    +   '<property id="Status" name="Status" old="' + @status + '" new="Closed" />'
                    +   '<collections />'
                    + '</change>'

-- THIS DOES NOT ERROR OUT AND DOES NOT DO ANYTHING!!
SET @changeSet.modify('insert sql:variable("@changeStatus") as last into (/changes)[1]')
```

The overall structure of the XML is:

```
<changes>
  <change id="" by="" byAccountId="" when="">
    <property />
    <collections />
  </change>
</changes>
```

When I run the script and check the @changeSet before and after processing, they are identical.  i.e.:  The @changeStatus was never added to the XML contained in @changeSet.

If the original was:

```
<changes>
  <change id="change01" by="" byAccountId="" when="">
    <property ... />
    <collections />
  </change>
  <change id="change02" by="" byAccountId="" when="">
    <property ... />
    <collections />
  </change>
</changes>
```

I expected to see:

```
<changes>
  <change id="change01" by="" byAccountId="" when="">
    <property ... />
    <collections />
  </change>
  <change id="change02" by="" byAccountId="" when="">
    <property ... />
    <collections />
  </change>
  <change id="82ECB3C5-D3BA-4CD2-B62C-89C083E4BAA1" by="me@mydomain.com" byAccountId="1E910737-D78C-E711-9C04-00090FFE0001" when="2018-01-17T00:12:33.700Z">
    <property id="Status" name="Status" old="In Review" new="Closed" />
    <collections />
  </change>
</changes>
```

Does anyone see what might be wrong?

Comment: It seems to work http://rextester.com/UZX3465

Comment: It should work as intended. Here is my test: http://rextester.com/RNX55555

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should never create an XML on string level!

This has various side-effects.

- If one of the variables is `NULL` the whole string will be `NULL`
  Try `SELECT '<x>' + NULL + '</x>';`
- XML is not just *text with some fancy extras*. Using T-SQL's `FOR XML` will - for sure! - create valid XML. Now imagine one of your string contains forbidden characters...
  Try `SELECT '<x>' + 'The arrow "->" might appear in normal text' + '</x>';`
  And try to cast it to XML
- Many values are not stored in *readable* format but in some binary format. Depending on your system's settings the conversion of such types (numbers, date and time, BLOBs) will vary. Using `FOR XML` will use - for sure! - the correct format in and out. You can write anything within your XML, but on another system it might fail to read it.

Try it this way:

```
DECLARE @changeSet XML = N'<changes/>';
DECLARE @changeStatus XML;

SET @changeStatus=
(
    SELECT NEWID() AS [@id]
          ,'SomeAuthor' AS [@by]
          ,'SomeAuthorId' AS [@byAccountId]
          ,GETUTCDATE() AS [@when]
          ,'Status' AS [property/@id]
          ,'Status' AS [property/@name]
          ,'In Review' AS [property/@old]
          ,'Closed' AS [property/@new]
          ,'' AS [collections]
    FOR XML PATH('change')
);
--your code works fine
SET @changeSet.modify(N'insert sql:variable("@changeStatus") as last into (/changes)[1]');

--you see the first change integrated
SELECT @changeSet;
```

--Now let us create one more  element

```
SET @changeStatus=
(
    SELECT NEWID() AS [@id]
          ,'Another' AS [@by]
          ,'OneMore' AS [@byAccountId]
          ,GETUTCDATE() AS [@when]
          ,'Status' AS [property/@id]
          ,'Status' AS [property/@name]
          ,'In Review' AS [property/@old]
          ,'Closed' AS [property/@new]
          ,'' AS [collections]
    FOR XML PATH('change')
);

--and insert it
SET @changeSet.modify(N'insert sql:variable("@changeStatus") as last into (/changes)[1]');

--yeah, worked!
SELECT @changeSet;
```

Answer (score 0):

The query you posted works in general. I ran following test:

http://rextester.com/RNX55555

However, if any of the injected parameters is null, the change will not be inserted and no error will be thrown as you try to insert `NULL` aka nothing.